# How to sum n highest values by row using dplyr without reshaping?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to create a new column based on the *n* highest values per row of a data frame.

Take the following example:

```
library(tibble)
df <- tribble(~name, ~q_1, ~q_2, ~q_3, ~sum_top_2,
              "a", 4, 1, 5, 9,
              "b", 2, 8, 9, 17)
```

Here, the **sum_top_2** column sums the 2 highest values of columns prefixed with "**q_**". I would like to generalize to the *n* highest values by row. How can I do this using `dplyr` without reshaping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is [`pmap`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/radiant/versions/0.1.95/topics/pmap) from `purrr` to loop over the rows of the columns that `starts_with` 'q_', by `sort`ing the row in `decreasing` order, get the first 'n' sorted elements with `head` and `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
n <- 2
df %>% 
   mutate(!! str_c("sum_top_", n) := pmap_dbl(select(cur_data(), 
           starts_with('q_')), 
            ~ sum(head(sort(c(...), decreasing = TRUE), n))))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  name    q_1   q_2   q_3 sum_top_2
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1 a         4     1     5         9
2 b         2     8     9        17
```

---

Or use `rowwise` from `dplyr`.

```
df %>% 
   rowwise %>% 
   mutate(!! str_c("sum_top_", n) := sum(head(sort(c_across(starts_with("q_")), 
           decreasing = TRUE), n))) %>% 
   ungroup
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  name    q_1   q_2   q_3 sum_top_2
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1 a         4     1     5         9
2 b         2     8     9        17
```

Comment: I haven't checked SO for some time. It seems that dplyr has been improving a lot.

Comment: @jazzurro Glad to see you here.  i think efficiency wise data.table would be still better

Comment: I agree with you in that point.  I have been learning and using other packages for my work. I think I will have time to catch up coming summer.  I am glad that you are still rocking here. :)